# Snowflake-SQL: Convert Data from month name in different language

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

To convert a date-string that contains the name of the month in a data-field I could use

```
select to_date('01October2022', 'DDMMMMYYYY')
```

..I didn't find a way to convert the string if the month name is not english e.g. in german like 01Oktober2022

I'm aware of this solution:

```html
create  or replace function monthname_2_value(date_value string)
  returns string
  as
  $$
    case
        when  lower(date_value) like '%januar%'     then replace(lower(date_value), 'januar',      '01')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%feburar%'    then replace(lower(date_value), 'feburar',     '02')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%märz%'       then replace(lower(date_value), 'märz',        '03')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%april%'      then replace(lower(date_value), 'april',       '04')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%mai%'        then replace(lower(date_value), 'mai',         '05')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%juni%'       then replace(lower(date_value), 'juni',        '06')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%juli%'       then replace(lower(date_value), 'juli',        '07')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%august%'     then replace(lower(date_value), 'august',      '08')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%september%'  then replace(lower(date_value), 'september',   '09')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%oktober%'    then replace(lower(date_value), 'oktober',     '10')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%november%'   then replace(lower(date_value), 'november',    '11')
        when  lower(date_value) like '%dezember%'   then replace(lower(date_value), 'dezember',    '12')
    end
  $$
  ;

select to_date(monthname_2_value('01Oktober2022'), 'DDMMYYYY')
```

Comment: Are you looking for a native alternative or just a more robust version of the function that you've included?  If you are looking for a more robust function, you could find a good translation API and create an external function that translates to the English month names, which can then be used for native SQL.

Comment: Actually I would like somebody to say: "you just switch the current session-language  by "set language = german"..but I think that is not going to happen. I think I will go with the current version or the one that has been provided by Felipe. If I find the time I may try to do your approach - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter SQL UDF to replace the month name with its number:

```sql
create or replace function replace_month(x string)
returns string
as $$
select regexp_replace(x, '[^0-9]+', o[regexp_substr(lower(x), '[^0-9]+')])
from (select object_construct('märz','03', 'oktober','10', 'november','11', 'dezember', 12) o)
$$
;
```

You can use it like this:

```sql
select replace_month('01März2022');

-- 01032022
```

Answer (score 1):

If want you want is to get the localized version for dayofweek or month, there is not built-in in SF but it can be achieved with a couple of UDFs

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_MONTHNAME_LONG_UDF(idx float, locale STRING) 
returns STRING
language javascript
as
$$
// ( 0 - January, 1 - Februaary, etc), this will work
  var objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(1);
  objDate.setMonth(IDX-1);
  return objDate.toLocaleString(LOCALE, { month: "long" });
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_MONTHNAME_SHORT_UDF(idx float, locale STRING) 
returns STRING
language javascript
as
$$
// ( 0 - January, 1 - Februaary, etc), this will work
  var objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(1);
  objDate.setMonth(IDX-1);
  return objDate.toLocaleString(LOCALE, { month: "short" });
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_WEEKDAY_LONG_UDF(idx float, locale STRING) 
returns STRING
language javascript
as
$$  
  // ( 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, etc), this will work:
  var objDate = new Date("2022/01/02");  // This is sunday
  objDate.setDate(objDate.getDate() + IDX);  
  return objDate.toLocaleString(LOCALE, { weekday: "long" });
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_WEEKDAY_SHORT_UDF(idx float, locale STRING) 
returns STRING
language javascript
as
$$  
  // Assuming it starts on Sunday 
  // (as in getDay: 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, etc), this will work:
  var objDate = new Date("2022/01/02");  // This is sunday
  objDate.setDate(objDate.getDate() + IDX);  
  return objDate.toLocaleString(LOCALE, { weekday: "short" });
$$;
```

You can then use it like:

```
SELECT GET_MONTHNAME_LONG_UDF(1,'ru')
```

or

```
SELECT GET_MONTHNAME_LONG_UDF(1,'pt')
```

To get your monthname on other locales.

For want was asked you can then do:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TRANSLATE_MONTHNAME_LONG_UDF(
    datestring STRING, type STRING,
    replaceType String, locale STRING) 
returns STRING
language javascript
as
$$
// ( 0 - January, 1 - Februaary, etc), this will work
  function pad2(number) {
    return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number
  }
  var replacement = "number";
  if (REPLACETYPE.toUpperCase() == "TEXT")
  {
    replacement = "text";
  }
  var objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(1);
  var month_names = [];
  for (var i=0;i<12;i++)
  {
     objDate.setMonth(i);
     month_name_locale = objDate.toLocaleString(LOCALE, { month: "long" });
     var replaceValue = (replacement=="number")?pad2(i):objDate.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
     DATESTRING = DATESTRING.replace(new RegExp(month_name_locale,'i'),replaceValue);
  }
  return DATESTRING;
$$;

-- instead of this select to_date('01Oktober2022', 'DDMMMMYYYY')
select to_date(TRANSLATE_MONTHNAME_LONG_UDF('01Oktober2022','long','text','de'),'DDMMMMYYYY');
```